# Creating meshgrids with combinations of rows between two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given the two 2d arrays `x` and `y` of the same shape but with different values.

I want to create an array of `meshgrids` between each row in x and y like so:

```
import numpy as np
x = np. array([[  0. ,   2.5,   5. ],
               [  0. ,   5. ,  10. ]])
y = np.array([[ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ],
              [ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ]])

meshgrids = []
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    xy = np.array(np.meshgrid(x[i],y[i]))
    xy = np.vstack([xy[1].ravel(), xy[0].ravel()]).T
    meshgrids.append(xy)

meshgrids = np.array(meshgrids)
print repr(meshgrids)

'''
# returns
array([[[  0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   0.5],
        [  0. ,   1. ],
        [  2.5,   0. ],
        [  2.5,   0.5],
        [  2.5,   1. ],
        [  5. ,   0. ],
        [  5. ,   0.5],
        [  5. ,   1. ]],

       [[  0. ,   0. ],
        [  0. ,   1. ],
        [  0. ,   2. ],
        [  5. ,   0. ],
        [  5. ,   1. ],
        [  5. ,   2. ],
        [ 10. ,   0. ],
        [ 10. ,   1. ],
        [ 10. ,   2. ]]])
'''
```

Is it possible to generate the array above without the python loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
m1,n1 = x.shape
m2,n2 = y.shape
out = np.empty((m1,n2,n1,2), dtype=np.result_type(x.dtype, y.dtype))
out[:,:,:,0] = y[:,:,None]
out[:,:,:,1] = x[:,None,:]
meshgrids = out.reshape(m1,-1,2)
```